# Virtualbox guest Alt key works as AltGr

Tags: debian, virtualbox, alt, keymapping

I have a Windows 10 as main os on my laptop and i have a virtual machine with Debian + i3wm with Virtualbox. I code on Vim (terminal text editor) and i have many shortcuts that use (Left) Alt key but my os have assigned by default (Right) AltGr action to (Left) Alt key. I try to change the keyboad keymap but doesn't solve it.

Have any idea?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but AltGr is usually different when using an international keyboard layout (US International for example). Have you tried switching to another layout? Also, does your AltGr behaves as Alt?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Only changing to default keyboard configuration and disable terminal emulator keybindings with ALT key.

Thanks for all!!